# Rust: not exposing a shared library

Tags: rust, crate

I'm looking for best practice defining a project structure in Rust. Let's say I have a project that consists of a client and a server component, and they share some functionality I'd like to move to a separate common library. So all in all, like this:

```
my_awesome_project
 - common [library]
 - client [binary] - uses common
 - server [binary] - uses common
```

Obviously, all methods in the `common` crate used in either `client` or `server` must be public. However, I would like to avoid anyone who has the `client` binary (not the code) being able to call methods from `common`. Is that possible somehow?

I come from C# background, where `common` would be a DLL exposing public methods, easily callable. I've read that Rust uses static linking by default, but in my understanding, that does not provide what I am looking for.

And yes, I could double the `common` code in a private module for both `server` and `client`, but that's not optimal either.

Comment: I don't understand, won't they be callable in C#? Anyway, with static linking you won't have a DLL and you won't have a way to call the library's methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the extent that you have *any* control over what someone does with your code, Rust's static linking will sufficiently obfuscate the library boundary that you need not worry about the methods being callable.

You will not deliver the library to the user. You will deliver a single binary, hopefully stripped of debug information, which contains the code of client and all the code from common it needs, bundled together.

Unlike C#, there is no separate DLL file, and no metadata that makes it easy to discover and use library functions.

Comment: OK, so I just misunderstood how exactly static linking works. Thanks, that helps!